# Transfer music from ubuntu 18.04 to Android device

Tags: android, music, rhythmbox, banshee

I bought a Galaxy s9, an android device.

I have it plugged in via USB to my desktop computer running Ubuntu 18.04.
I've set the screen to remain unlocked for the maximum amount of time allowable with manual intervention (10 minutes).

The device can't been in Banshee or Rhythmbox.
(A few hours ago it was visible in Rhythmbox, but attempts to transfer files yielded errors. From what I remember the errors said "device not available for writing)

The device can be seen in gnome's file explorer. However, when I click on the icon for the device I see the error "Unable to access SAMSUNG Android. Unable to open mtp device [usb:003,004]"

I'd love to be able to simply manage music on the device.
Managing playlists would also be awesome.

Is this possible? If I google for these errors I see issues going back many years and get the impression that managing an android device from ubuntu is simply impossible for a user without linux system administration skills.

Answer (score 3):

On Android, pull down your top bar after connecting the phone. You will see a notification "USB charging this device". Tap that and you will see that it defaults to only charging your device. Thus, you can, by default, not mount the drive. Tap "transfer files" on your Android phone to have it mounted in your file manager. To unmount it, you can use the same screen on your Android phone, or use Files.

After this, you can transfer music files, or eventually access it with your music playing software.

Comment: cool, then open it with google play music